# CodeIgniter: How to pass $this->db->insert_id() value to Controller in order to be inserted in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, xampp

I'm trying to insert fields to a table and grab the id (assume that the table's PRIMARY KEY is AUTO INCREMENT). I need that record's auto incremental ID to be inserted in a second table. I can obviously return $this->db->insert_id() but how do I access the value in Controller thereafter?

I tried to define it in a variable and access in the controller but it didn't work.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: insert_id
Filename: controllers/POS.php
Line Number: 87
```

**Model:**

```
function populate_pos_purchase_table($posPurchase) {
    $this->db->trans_begin();
    $this->db->insert('pos_purchase', $posPurchase);

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $this->db->trans_commit();
        $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        return $insert_id;
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
function update_payment_details() {

$newPayment = array (
    'pos_id' => $insert_id, // Line Number: 87
    'payment_description' => 'Point of Sales',
    'payment_method' => $this->input->post('payment_method'),
    'payment_date' => $this->input->post('payment_date'),
    'paid_amount' => $this->input->post('total'),
    'due_amount' => 0
);

$this->pos_model->populate_new_payment_table($newPayment);  
$this->index();

}
```

Comment: In your model, a function cannot return twice back-to-back like that. See the docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php.

"If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call. return will also end the execution of an eval() statement or script file."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save the id from the first insert - then use it in the second?

```
function update_payment_details() {

$insert_id = populate_pos_purchase_table($posPurchase);

$newPayment = array (
    'pos_id' => $insert_id, // Line Number: 87
    'payment_description' => 'Point of Sales',
    'payment_method' => $this->input->post('payment_method'),
    'payment_date' => $this->input->post('payment_date'),
    'paid_amount' => $this->input->post('total'),
    'due_amount' => 0
);

$this->pos_model->populate_new_payment_table($newPayment);  
$this->index();

}
```

Comment: Yup! $insert_id = $this->pos_model->populate_pos_purchase_table($posPurchase); worked in the Controller. Thanks.